# How to integrated mender within lk-bootloader base-on Yocto Project

Tags: yocto, ota

I am new for yocto ,now I use a MTK-demo-board to build a linux-distro base on Yocto.  I want to realize OTA by mender followed this tutorial:https://docs.mender.io/1.0/Devices/Integrating-with-U-Boot.

but Mender support u-boot as bootloader by default, the MTK use lk bootloader,Then how to realize this function?

The AP which I used is MT8183,The steps I have done list below:
1. /meta/meta-mediatek/recipes-bsp/lk/lk_2.0.0.0.bb .  add follow code:

```
require recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot-mender.inc
PROVIDES += "u-boot"
RPROVIDES_{PN} += "u-boot"
```

2.cp lk_2.0.0.0 lk-fw-utils_2.0.0.0,and changed the file as behind:

```
 a. delete do_genkey{} function;
 b. add EXTRA_OEMAKE_class-target = 'CROSS_COMPILE=${TARGET_PREFIX} CC="${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS}" V=1' 
 c. add "oe_runmake env" in function do_compile()
 d. add PROVIDES_${PN} = "lk-fw-utils"
        RPROVIDES_${PN} = "lk-fw-utils"
        DEPENDS += "mtd-utils"
```

3./build/local.conf,add these code

```
  MENDER_ARTIFACT_NAME = "release-1"
  INHERIT += "mender-full"
  MACHINE = "aiv8183m1v2"
  PREFERRED_VERSION_pn-mender = "1.0.%"
  PREFERRED_VERSION_pn-mender-artifact = "1.0.%"
  PREFERRED_VERSION_pn-mender-artifact-native = "1.0.%"

  DISTRO_FEATURES_append = "systemd"
  VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemed"
  DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED = "sysvinit"
  VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts = ""
  IMAGE_FSTYPES = "ext4"
```

4.execute bitbake-layers add-layer /meta/meta-mender/meta-mender-core

5.bitbake-layers create-layer meta-mylayer,in this layer,I mkdir -p /recipes-mender/mender/files, in directory mender,I touch mender_%.bbappend file as bellow:

```
FILESEXTARPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/file:"
SRC_URI_append = "file://server.crt"
and put servert.crt in the the file directory.
```

6.in the mancine.conf(aiv8183m1v2.conf),I have added

```
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_u-boot-fw-utils = "lk-fw-utils"
  PREFERRED_PROVIDER_u-boot = "lk"
  IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "kernel-modules"
  MENDER_STORAGE_DEVICE = "/dev/mmcblk0"
```

7./meta-mender/meta-mender-core/classes/mender-full.bbclass

```
 MENDER_FEATURES_ENABLE_append_arm = ""
  MENDER_FEATURES_ENABLE_append_aarch64 = ""
```

the result I expected is the linux can OTA over mender.
But,actual results is the project can't cross build.the log says:

```
DEBUG: Executing shell function soft_link_to_rootfs 
| ln: target ‘mender.bmap’ is not a directory 
| WARNING: /home/yewkui/yocto-linux/build/tmp/work/aiv8183m1v2-poky-linux/mtk-image-openmm-aiv/1.0-r0/temp/run.soft_link_to_rootfs.1347217:1 exit 1 from 'ln -nfs mtk-image-openmm-aiv-aiv8183m1v2-20181224064735.rootfs.ext4 mender mender.bmap /home/yewkui/yocto-linux/build/tmp/deploy/images/aiv8183m1v2/rootfs.ext4 mender mender.bmap' 
| DEBUG: Python function do_rootfs finished 
| ERROR: Function failed: soft_link_to_rootfs (log file is located at /home/yewkui/yocto-linux/build/tmp/work/aiv8183m1v2-poky-linux/mtk-image-openmm-aiv/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.1347217) 
ERROR: Task (/home/yewkui/yocto-linux/meta/poky/../meta-mediatek-mt8183/recipes-aiv/images/mtk-image-openmm-aiv.bb:do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1' 
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2392 tasks of which 2391 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed. 
NOTE: Writing buildhistory
```

---

---

Maybe I am wrong at first step,but how to realize the OTA by yocto base on MTK lk-bootloader,please help! thanks a lot!

Comment: Any other OTA software recommend is appreciate

Comment: I favor RAUC since it is more flexible in my opinion. However, integrating an update technology for someone who is new to yocto is really hard stuff.
I suggest you to try the latest mender version with a new poky release.

Comment: I think the problem is lk-bootloader which is not match with Mender or RAUC.

Comment: @FabianKnapp Is lk a forks of u-boot?